# TableView cell on iPad refusing to accept clear color

Tags: ios, uitableview, background, uicolor

I am using a github project called SWTableViewCell.h by Chris Wendel. On the iPhone, clear color works. However, on an iPad it refuses to make the tableview cell clear. Instead, it makes it white. I have been wracking my brain how to fix this but cannot. I have even tried to set the background based on a png, but it just will not work. What types of alternatives can I go about to solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the documentation for the project on GitHub, there is a method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Set background color of cell here if you don't want default white
}
```

Change it to this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Comment: Wow. That was it. Thank you. I'll check it when the time limit lets me.

Comment: Hello, This perfectly works. Can you please  confirm, is this a bug in iPad?
why we need implement above method.